# TERADATA HELP COLUMN

Tags: teradata

```
Database ua_dillards;  
HELP TABLE deptinfo; 
HELP COLUMN nullable FROM deptinfo;
```

.... writing these queries but always end up with this error:

> ... Error Code - 5628 Error Message - [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC
>   15.10.00.05] [Error 5628] [SQLState HY000] Column nullable not found in UA_DILLARDS.deptinfo.,,,,, HELP!!

But column **Nullable** is present in data table... cross checked using **HELP TABLE**.

I am writing these queries in **TERADATA VIEWPOINT**.

Answer (score 1):

for all the information about a column `help column deptinfo.nullable;`

or you may query the dbc-table directly

`select ColumnName, Nullable from dbc.columnsV where databasename ='ua_dillards' and TableName = 'deptinfo'`

Answer (score 0):

`Nullable` is a column in the result set of a `HELP TABLE`.

The rows of that result are the columns in the table.

Btw, most people prefer `SHOW TABLE` over `HELP TABLE`.